# Learning Nynorsk as a non-norwegian speaker

Tags: norwegian, germanic-languages

I am a non-norwegian person who wishes to learn Nynorsk. I don't live in Norway and I also don't know the norwegian language except for a few words. I want to learn Nynorsk even before I learn Bokmål.  Perhaps learning Nynorsk first is a very ambitious idea, but at least I want to try. The only material for learning Nynorsk targeted at non-norwegians I've found is the text ***Norwegian Nynorsk: An Introduction for Foreign Students*** by Peter Hallaråker. Now, I don't think a single text will suffice to learn Nynorsk, so my question is: Is there other material similar to this text? In the sense that its target audience are non-norwegian speakers who want to learn Nynorsk. It doesn't necessarily have to be a book, any other type of resource is equally appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Languages are always capitalized in English: non-Norwegian speaker

Comment: @Lambie Thanks for the correction! Will edit soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good luck! It is not easy to find resources for nynorsk. Eg bor i Noreg og kan bokmål, men ikkje ordentleg nynorsk.

You might just learn bokmål and start also reading things in nynorsk. Reading skills will come quite fast after an initial shock. And then you can use bokmål-nynorsk -materials.

The website https://nynorsksenteret.no/nynorsk-for-innvandrarar/vaksenopplaering has material for teaching nynorsk to adult immigrants. Maybe some of those resources also work for self-study.

I checked a few recent bachelor's theses on teaching nynorsk to adults, and they mention Nynorskpluss, but a quick search did not find an active resource with that name. They did not cite other books besides the one you name yourself. You can find academic material by for example a Google scholar search: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=nynorsk+voksenoppl%C3%A6ring (and similar search terms).

Tatoeba has a bunch of sentences in nynorsk. You could see how to export those to for example Anki and build your own resources that way.

But it seems that there are not that many resources in general. As mentioned, good luck.

Comment: Nynorsk is just modern Norwegian.

Comment: @Lambie that statement ... varies from truth. A Nynorsk text may be archaic or modern, just like any Bokmål text (or any other language, for that matter).